# Delphi Android password protect a file

Tags: android, delphi, password-protection

Is there any way of password protecting a file? Currently I'm copying a file to a local Documents path, but I need it to be password protected.

```
var
  BackupPath, BackupFile, OriginPath, OriginFile: string;
begin
BackupPath := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath + '/some_back.db';
OriginPath := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(TPath.GetHomePath, 'some.db');
ShowMessage(OriginPath);
TFile.Copy(OriginPath, BackupPath, true);
```

Comment: Surely the OS implements security?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well when I export the some_back.db it can easily be accessed by simply downloading a DB viewer, but I need some kind of a password that I can put on the some_back.db.

Comment: OS level security would only allow authorised users to access the file. If you don't want to use such facilities, encrypt the file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Would it be possible to put a password on a TZipFile?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head whether that class offers such functionality. Did you research its documentation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've looked into it, but I see no evidence on it having a password protection, but wanted to still ask since maybe I could've missed it.

Comment: What's not clear is whether or not you want the file to be secure, or how secure you want it. Just requiring a password doesn't make it secure. Plenty of password protected ZIP files are insecure. Security isn't something that you can apply without in depth knowledge. I suspect you are underestimating the complexity of your problem, whatever it actually is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is there something you don't understand? I don't want NOTHING  complex, no deep security I need to get a method to put a password on a file so, people who are working cant access that file, but people with the password can go ahead and open it!

Comment: You don't mind if somebody can crack the password in a couple of minutes? And what about the period of time when it is decrypted and your program is operating on it, it will be easy to copy at that point.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan As I mentioned, I need it password protected so the Workers cant access it, the file is on a Scanner which runs on Android, the Scanner is in a warehouse, when we have to do inventarization ( Don't know how its in english) I need a backup so we can go and check if everything is working good, but in the mean time have a password so nobody can change anything.

Comment: The answer you accepted is my first comment expanded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your app, and other apps cannot access them (nor can the user, unless they have root access). [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#filesInternal).

But if you need to export the file, and protect it once exported, you might restrict export to **a location which itself is protected**.

For example, you could offer export only to a user's Dropbox/Google Drive/(*insert your cloud storage provider here*).

This way, the file will only leave the secure area when the user wants it.